# Delete value of searchbar when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to ask on how you could delete the value of the searchbar. I thought of using jQuery, and Javascripting. This is what my codes looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchbarClicked {
document.getElementById('searchbar').value = '';
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="searchbar" value='search...' onclick='searchbarClicked'>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search"></br>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `function searchbarClicked {` should be `function searchbarClicked() {`. There is a typo in your code. You have missed `()`

Comment: it didn't worked according to my expected output.

Comment: @user3324227 Look answer bellow

Comment: @user3324227, I have given answer with demo. Hope It works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
<input type="text" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is missing the id:

`<input type="text" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" value='search...' onclick='searchbarClicked'>`

Comment: @Satpal > do you think there is something wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. Your input is missing the id as @henriquea already pointed out
2. `function searchbarClicked {` should be `function searchbarClicked() {`. There is a typo in your code. You have missed `()`
3. You have to use `onclick='searchbarClicked()'` instead of `onclick='searchbarClicked'`. You have missed `()`

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" id="searchbar" name="searchbar" value='search...' onclick='searchbarClicked()'>
```

*JavaScript*

```
function searchbarClicked() {
    document.getElementById('searchbar').value = '';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AeELX/)

I really hate inline event binding. So I suggest you to use

*HTML*

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search"></br>
```

*JavaScript*

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('searchbar').onclick = function () {
        this.value = '';
    }
}
```

[**DEMO without inline event binding**](http://jsfiddle.net/AeELX/3/)